# Creating a folder named after the current date and time

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a powershell script that creates a new folder with the current date (formatted as yyyy-MM-dd) as a name.

Here's what I have so far:

```
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop> powershell.exe -command "new-item ($(get-location)
+ (Get-Date).year + "-" + (Get-Date).month + "-" + (Get-Date).day) -type directo
ry"
Die Benennung "C:\Users\me\Desktop" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, ein
er Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überp
rüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern ent
halten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:35
+ new-item (C:\Users\me\Desktop <<<<  + (Get-Date).year +  - + (Get-Date).
month + - + (Get-Date).day) -type directory
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\j.moore\Desktop:String
) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 New-Item "$((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))" -ItemType directory
```

or:

```
md "$((get-date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
```

Explanation from [this site](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/01/22/hey-powershell-guy-how-can-i-create-a-new-folder-using-a-name-based-on-the-current-date.aspx):

> $() enables you to use  the output of a command in a string
>
> The ()  around get-date again say "Execute this first" so that we can
>   use the Methods of the DateTime Object returned by get-date
>
> the toString() Method of a DateTime object takes a formattingstring as
>   input.

Comment: Using an expandable string with a subexpression is more complicated than needed.

Comment: While `(Get-Date).ToString(...)` works, `Get-Date -Format ...` is more idiomatic PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mkdir (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")
```